# Excel to extract time from DD/MM/YYYY PMXX:XX

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to convert `DD/MM/YYYY PMXX:XX` *(in text format)* into `XX:XX` *(in time format)*

For example:

```
17/7/2017 PM1:08 -> 13:08
1/7/2017 AM1:08  -> 01:08
```

Comment: =time(A1) with your date being in A1

Comment: How does your computer normally display time? Is the value as you displayed it here a valid date/time value on your machine or is it treated as text?

Comment: rubbush. That wont work the time function takes three arguments. Hour, minute, second.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148100/convert-date-e-g-jun-05-2016-080000-to-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss/38149642#38149642) has a description of the multiple processes that will work for pulling the date or the time.  You will just need to tweak the formulas a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
=TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND("M",A1)+1,5))+IF(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,1)="P",0.5,0)
```

[image]

Format the result with your preferred time format.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. Need to study how you do that! :)